# add option address for email header

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin that I have written to send a duplicate email of any woocommerce order to an alternate email address (the accountant in this situation)

I have it setup where there is a settings page with an email input field. This works, it validates the address and adds the input to the options/database.

```
   add_option( 'woobcc_option_name', '');
   register_setting( 'woobcc_options_group', 'woobcc_option_name', 'woobcc_callback' );
}
```

I  have uninstalled hook to remove the data and option from the database if the plugin is deactivated/uninstalled.

I can echo to the page, using `<?php echo get_option('woobcc_option_name'); ?>` and that works also.

Originally I had it hardcoded like this:

```
if( 'new_order' == $email_id ){
        $headers .= "Bcc: Name <recipient@address.com>" . "\r\n";
    }
    return $headers;
```

However, with the addition of the options panel and database option, should I be using:
`$headers .= "Bcc: Name <<?php echo get_option('woobcc_option_name'); ?>>" . "\r\n";`
 or
`echo .woobcc_option_name.;`

or what?

I don't know the right way to add the mail from the options input to the headers using the option data. Knowing me, its probably something along the simpler line :)

Comment: If `'new_order' == $email_id` is true then `$email_id` is NOT an email address. Have you setup other `$var` for email address?

Comment: the "new_order" is a woocommerce construct and sends the order details to the buyer, whenever a new order/purchase is made. All I am doing is sending a copy of the email to another address. The var as you say is something I'm trying to setup using the settings input field. I'm trying to get away from having to manually code in addresses.

Comment: `if( 'new_order' == $email_id ) ` means: IF `string('new_order')` EQUALS to `$email_id`. If you add: `'` or `"` then its NOT construct but a String.

Answer (score 0):

You should add headers as **Array** try:

```
if( 'new_order' === $email_id ){
    $headers[] = "Bcc: Name <recipient@address.com>";
}
return $headers;
```

Sample from WordPress:

```
// assumes $to, $subject, $message have already been defined earlier...

$headers[] = 'From: Me Myself <me@example.net>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: John Q Codex <jqc@wordpress.org>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: iluvwp@wordpress.org';

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Comment: That would mean I would have to code in the addresses - and that's where the settings page comes in - so it uses the address from there. I'm trying to get away from having to manually code in addresses. its also sending a COPY of a woocommerce email, so all the to, subject message are predefined - AND, no need to cc, as its already a bcc.

Comment: Yes, no need to add cc. You need to add the Bcc header as array only. The problem now is only the string: `'new_order'` replace this string with the function or var where you have the email address to match `$email_id`.

Comment: I'm still trying to get my head around this. All Im trying to do is use the <?php echo get_option('woobcc_option_name'); ?> in the $headers .= "Bcc: Name <recipient@address.com>" . "\r\n";

It echos the address just fine. How to write it so it uses the 'woobcc_option_name'. Most of the answers seem to be using a coded address which Im trying to avoid.

Write it like this? .= "Bcc: Name <?php echo get_option('woobcc_option_name'); ?>" . ?

Comment: Should be: `$headers .= "Bcc: Name ".get_option('woobcc_option_name');`
If Array then: `$headers[] = "Bcc: Name ".get_option('woobcc_option_name');`
Try also this:
`$headers[] = "Bcc: Name <".get_option('woobcc_option_name').">";`